# Flask Blueprint returns NameError when trying to register blueprint on the app in __init__ file

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am getting `NameError: name 'i_statement_bp' is not defined` while trying to register bluepring named `i_statement_bp` with the app in ABC/app/`__init__.py`.
I have `Flask app` with `Blueprints` with the following structure:

```
ABC/
 |- run.py
 |- app/
     |--__init__.py
     |
     |--i_statement/
     |        |--__init__.py
     |        |
     |        |--templates/
     |        |        |--i_statement.html
     |        |
     |        |--i_statement.py
     |       
     |--blog/
     |
     |--static/
            |
            |--images/
            |--css/
            |--js/
            |--fonts/
```

My `ABC/app/__init__.py` looks as follows:

```
import flask from Flask, Blueprint

class MyApp(Flask):
 def __init__(self):
    Flask.__init__(self, __name__)  
    self.jinja_loader=jinja2.ChoiceLoader([self.jinja_loader,
    jinja2.PrefixLoader({}, delimiter = ".")])

    def create_global_jinja_loader(self):
        return self.jinja_loader

    def register_blueprint(self, bp):
        Flask.register_blueprint(self, bp)
        self.jinja_loader.loaders[1].mapping[bp.name] = bp.jinja_loader

app=MyApp()

app.register_blueprint(i_statement_bp) **<== this line of code is causing error per debugger** 

from app.i_statement import i_statement_bp
```

`__init__.py` file in the `i_statement' folder is empty, just to indicate that this is package to Python.

The file called `i_statement.py` looks as follows:

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify, session

i_statement_bp=Blueprint('i_statement_bp',__name__,
url_prefix='/i_statement',template_folder="templates")

@i_statement_bp.route('/i_statement',methods=['GET','POST'])
  def i_statement():
     some logic here
     return render_template('i_statement.html',variable=variable)
```

As additional info, the reason for MyApp class is desire to have templates folder within blueprint folder as opposed to typical approach where templates folder is located in app folder.

The `ABC/run.py` file looks as follows:

```
from app import app

app.secret_key=flask_secret_key

app.run(debug=debug)
```

Update:
as per suggestion in comments, I have switched lines in `ABC/app/__init__.py` as follows:

```
from app.i_statement import i_statement_bp
app.register_blueprint(i_statement_bp)
```

This arrangement produces the new type of error:

```
from app import app
File "C:\ABC\app\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
from app.i_statement import i_statement_bp
ImportError: cannot import name 'i_statement_bp' from 'app.i_statement'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like

```
from app.i_statement import i_statement_bp
```

is imported after

```
app.register_blueprint(i_statement_bp)
```

Try switching the order of those statements.

Update:

Try instead

```
from app.i_statement.i_statement import i_statement_bp
```

for your second error.

Notice how you have the folder `i_statement` and then the file `i_statement.py` and so you need two of them.

Comment: Tried to do that - getting error now in `run.py` file in the `ABC` folder: the first line there goes `from app import app` which is what causing error, then it cascades into the error in the `ABC/app/__init__.py` file in the following line `from app.i_statement import i_statement_bp` ImportError: cannot import name 'i_statement_bp' from 'app.i_statement'

Comment: Can you please append an "Edit: ..." to your question or post a new question with the new error message?

Comment: Also do you have two nested modules called app? I find it suspicious that you have a statement `from app import app`. Should it not be `from ABC import app` or something else?

Comment: No, I don't have two nested modules called app. The structure is `ABC/app/__init__.py` or for Blueprint `ABC/app/i_statement/__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

Your are not importing bluprint's instance variable correctly.

It should be:

```
from app.i_statement.i_statement import i_statement_bp
```

You can also import using relative path to your sub package as it is sub package of you `app`.

```
from .i_statement.i_statement import i_statement_bp
```

then register imported bluprint to the instance of your app.

*Remember: Python is interpreted language, as it runs to downwards, variable used before the assignment will be never known.*

Comment: Confused by your first suggestion: `from app.i_statement import i_statement_bp` - that's exactly what I had.

Comment: Sorry that was typo.